# NDK use cmake arguments "-DANDROID_STL=c++_static" have compiler error

Tags: c++11

I am using ndk and want to use c++11 stl.

```
externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions"
                arguments "-DANDROID_STL=c++_static"
            }
}
```

But there is a compile error:

> G:\Users\zhouyi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\sources\cxx-stl\llvm-libc++\include\utility
>   Error:(332, 15) error: no viable overloaded '=' Error:(332, 15) error:
>   no viable overloaded '='

The error is in the utility file. The file in the llvm-libc++:

```
_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
pair& operator=(const pair& __p)
    _NOEXCEPT_(is_nothrow_copy_assignable<first_type>::value &&
               is_nothrow_copy_assignable<second_type>::value)
{
    first = __p.first;
    second = __p.second;
    return *this;
}
```

Can someone help me?